# Is this SpaceEngine atmosphere realistic?

Tags: atmosphere, water, oxygen

[image]

- Height of homogenous atmosphere: 15.26km
- Atmospheric pressure: 4.76 atm
- Air density: 4.8323kg/m^3
- Air temperature: 45.704°C
- Speed of sound: 364.65 m/sec
- Exosphere temperature: 1255.9°C
- Greenhouse effect: 34.562°C
- Average molar mass: 26.798
- Relative mass: 8.5298*10^-6
- Mass: 1.6981*10^19kg

Composition (PP stands for Partial Pressure):

- O2: 56.7% (PP: 2.7 atm)
- H2O: 22.8% (PP: 1.09 atm)
- N2: 20.2% (PP: 0.96 atm)
- CO2: 0.203% (PP: 0.00964 atm)
- SO2: 0.104% (PP: 0.00494 atm)
- Ar: 4.37ppm (PP: 2.08*10^-5 atm)
- CO: 0.0142ppm (PP: 6.77*10^-8 atm)

I am curious if this atmospheric composition would be at all plausible. The water vapour (H2O) content seems to be far too much, although this world has only 0.67x the gravity of Earth (which would allow more water vapour to stick around in the air). Also, I have heard that the upper bound/wildfire limit of oxygen in an atmosphere is 0.35/35% of 1 ATM partial pressure, but according to this paper it may not be: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-35081-z
If this atmosphere is impossible, what would a very similar but possible atmosphere consist of? I am trying to somewhat replicate conditions of Cave of the Crystals but with high oxygen (toxic levels) and water vapour that condenses in the lungs.

Update 1: I will be changing the water vapour content, sulphur dioxide content, carbon dioxide content and argon content. What values of each of these would fit best for my world? I would like sulphur dioxide to still have a partial pressure of 0.1ppm at least so it can have an odour but please tell me if this is also impossible.

Update 2: based on my current calculations, water vapour in this pressure and temperature should be no more than 8%, but this calculation is using Earth gravity, not lower gravity (0.67 g). I will lower sulphur dioxide further to Earth-similar levels and I will lower carbon dioxide too. Argon will be increased to just over 0.01 ATM in partial pressure. Nitrogen will fill in the missing gaps.

Comment: Please write down that table in the post. It's hard if not impossible to read as it is now

Comment: You can't have that $SO_2$ in an atmosphere with $O_2$ as it would combine with the oxygen to form $SO_3$ and that would combine with your water and water vapor to form $H_2SO_4$. So, you will get some sulfuric acid in your oceans. Also having that little argon means your planet is very young, as argon in the atmosphere forms when $^{40}K$ decays, which is one of the main sources of natural radiogenic heat in most rocky planets.

Comment: @L.Dutch Added list for now so values are easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix a few things about your atmosphere to make it stable. Currently, it is unstable.

## $SO_2$ and Oxygen

You have a 0.104% sulfur dioxide ($SO_2$) concentration and a 56.7% oxygen concentration. Sulfur Dioxide just loves to combine with oxygen to create sulfur trioxide ($SO_3$), which will then react with your water vapor in your atmosphere and form sulfuric acid ($H_2SO_4$). Your oceans now consist of some dilute acid, so now you have no $SO_2$ and still a lot of oxygen.

To solve this problem, I would suggest you remove the sulfur dioxide from your atmosphere entirely or make it a trace gas, because I'm pretty sure you want to keep the oxygen, and it will go away anyways and leave behind acid (it's just a pain here).

## Argon

This is not really a problem, but your atmosphere has almost no argon in it. Having a very little amount of argon means your planet is very young, as argon in the atmosphere forms when $^{40}K$ decays, which is one of the main sources of natural radiogenic heat in most rocky planets.

This is not really a problem, but it is just to let you know. You could solve this by increasing the amount of argon or simply making your atmosphere artificial.

## Problems for Potential Life

### Water Vapor

I don't thing that water vapor will cause problems to life if it adapts to that high concentration, but the amount of water vapor you listed is obviously unnatural. On Earth, even at max humidity, you probably will only get 5% water vapor with normal amounts at 0.4%.

Also, water vapor is a greenhouse gas, so that much water vapor will make your planet molten.

**EDIT**: You also have 5 times as much $CO_2$ in the atmosphere in earth's atmosphere. Your planet will be even more molten.

### Oxygen

You have a lot of oxygen and earth vegetation would really burn. This isn't a problem though, as if your native life evolved chlorine defenses (chlorine isn't flammable), you might be able to escape this problem.

## Summary

This atmosphere is not going to work. The sulfur dioxide can not exist, you have too little argon (which isn't as much as a problem as it could be), and your planet will be molten from the water vapor.

I would suggest for you to make the sulfur dioxide a trace gas and significantly decrease the water vapor content and slightly decrease the oxygen levels.

Comment: Noted. With SO2 removed (turned into trace gas) and Argon increased, how much water vapour at maximum would I be able to have in this atmosphere? Also, would the vapour alone when combined with the high air temperature still condense in the lungs and cause pulmonary damage?

Comment: @casualworldbuilder I don't know, because you haven't given me all the info on your planet that I would need, but I would suggest that you make the water vapor down to earth like levels (0.4%) and increase the amount of nitrogen to take its place.

Comment: the world is actually a moon and both the planet and moon orbit 0.41 AU away from a K type star. The moon has a 1/3 the mass of Earth, receives higher insolation than Earth but has a higher albedo (0.54) and has less surface water (41% of surface) compared to Earth.

Comment: @casualworldbuilder We have a 1 question policy, so I would suggest that you make this another question. There are other people who could answer your question better than me.

Comment: For your update, you really still can't have that much sulfur dioxide as it would form sulfuric acid. You could probably not smell it if you have oxygen in the atmosphere, and you would have it in the ppb range.

Comment: okay to simplify things I will go with what you’ve stated and use earth-similar levels of sulphur dioxide (around 15 ppb). I will lower carbon dioxide and increase argon too. As for water vapour, 8% would be the max for this world’s pressure and temperature but I am not sure how gravity would affect it.

Comment: @casualworldbuilder That sounds good.